# Polynomial with properties at its zeroes - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Take $P_{n+1}(\Re)$ to be the space of polynomials with coefficients in the real numbers, with the degree of all polynomials $\le n+1$. I want to show that, given any $n$ points $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \in \Re,$ $\exists f \in P_{n+1}(\Re), f\ne0,$ s.t. the function is zero at all of those points $a_i$, but the sum of the derivatives at those points is $0$.

I don't know where to start. The hint in the textbook says to use the dimension theorem, but I don't see how that can be used here.

Comment: Do you mean a polynomial other than $0$?

Comment: yes, a nonzero polynomial

Comment: Hints:  1. get a lower bound on the dimension of the vector space $V$ of polynomials of degree $n+1$ which vanish at each of the $a_i$.  2.  Consider the linear map $V\to \mathbb R$ which sums the derivatives of a polynomial at each of the $a_i$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Define the mapping from $P_{n+1}(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, defined as

$$p\mapsto \left[p(a_1), p(a_2),\dots, p(a_n), \sum_{i=1}^n p'(a_n)\right]$$

and notice that it is a linear mapping.

Answer (score 0):

**Another hint**:

Consider the map
\begin{align}
\varphi:P_{n+1} &\longrightarrow \bf R^{n+1}\\
f&\longmapsto\begin{bmatrix}f(a_1)\\f(a_2)\\\vdots\\f(a_n)\\\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f'(a_i)\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
You have to check that $\varphi$ is a linear map, and that $\;\dim(\ker\varphi)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure which dimension theorem you are referring to, but there is a dimension counting argument to get the answer.

The key thing to note is that "evaluation at $a_i$" $f\rightarrow f(a_i)$ is a linear map from your space of polynomials to the reals.

Then, note that differentiation is also a linear map $P_{n+1}(\Re)\rightarrow P_{n+1}(\Re)$, so composing and summing these gives that the "evaluate derivative at $a_i$ and sum" operator is linear, from $P_{n+1}(\Re)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

So then we have $n+1$ linear maps from $P_{n+1}(\Re)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the evaluations, and the "derivative then evaluate then sum". Then note, your space is $n+2$ dimensional.

At this point, you should be able to use a dimension theorem to give the final result, that there is a common zero to all of them. (though note that as stated, the zero map also works as a solution to the question).